# Full Calendar form Arshaw doesn't fit, it has a huge height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

Well the main problema that I have is that I can't make the fullCalendar from Arshaw to fit inside the div that I've assign to it. The div container has a height of 300px. But when I try to put the calendar inside that space, it renders a huge Calendar. When I open the browser console the height that it has is over 1500px. I've tried the height parameter, the container height, tried injecting css to the tags and nothing seems to work, I also deleted each jquery call and other scripts running in my page and just left the scripts that FullCalendar needs. At last I moved the calendar right after the  tag and it worked. I'm guessing the problem is the calculation of tables' height and that leads to have a bad calculation of each box insisde the table.

here are the pictures in case you guys don't understand: http://s1383.photobucket.com/user/dortegalizardo/library/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. On some point I don´t know why I had on my css

```
.myclass p{margin 20px 0;}
```

That was causing the problem with the height on each box of the calendar. The calendar was inside a div that was inside another div that had the class above.